# Eclipse CDT outline not displaying current function

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm running eclipse 4.2.1 (Juno) with the CDT plugin on linux.  I have the outline view linked with the editor and as the cursor moves around the file the outline follows correctly except that the highlighted selection is not inside the visible region of the outline.  So I have to scroll around in the outline to find the selection. Is there some configuration that needs to be changed or is this a bug?

Comment: Not sure what the correct procedure is on SO but I found that this bug has been identified as [Bug 391058](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=391058)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug which has been filed with the eclipse group as [Bug 391058](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=391058).